# Why can the CNOT representation $e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}\left(I-Z\right)\otimes\left(I-X\right)}$ hardly be found in books?

Tags: quantum-gate

The CNOT gate is usually written as

> $|0\rangle\langle0|\otimes I + 1\rangle\langle1|\otimes X$

(with $X,Y,Z$ being the Pauli Basis and $I$ the Identity).

I have yet to stumble across the representation [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controlled_NOT_gate) gives when looking at books on the topic:

> $e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}\left(I-Z\right)\otimes\left(I-X\right)}$

Why is it that none of the books on quantum mechanics / computing /information I have looked at uses this exponential representation? Does somebody know, which book does?

---

[Cross-posted on physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/709287/58382)

Comment: People probably don't quote the exponential formula because it doesn't make it clear what the gate is doing to basis states $|z_1z_2\rangle$. The exponential formula *does* give you a hint as to what kind of interaction might allow you to build a CNOT gate, though.

Comment: I think this exponential representation is useful if you want to build a Hamiltonian that recreates a CNOT.

Comment: Do you know of books that give the exponential representation?

Comment: @Mauricio In most cases, it would probably be more instructive to rewrite the CNOT as an exponential of $X\otimes X$ and correct with local Cliffords. I don't see the point of this representation. Usually, you can't choose your interactions.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do it by expanding the terms in the exponential:

$$
e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}(I−Z)\otimes(I−X)} = e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}(II - IX - ZI + ZX)}
$$

here I omitted the tensor product, e.g $II = I \otimes I$. Then you can group the diagonal and no diagonal operators as:

$$
e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}([II - ZI] + [ZX - IX])} = e^{i\frac{\pi}{4} \bigl( \bigl[ \begin{smallmatrix}0 & 0\\ 0 & 2I\end{smallmatrix}\bigr] + \bigl[ \begin{smallmatrix}0 & 0\\ 0 & -2X\end{smallmatrix}\bigr] \bigr)}
$$

The matrices $\bigl[ \begin{smallmatrix}0 & 0\\ 0 & 2I\end{smallmatrix}\bigr] $ and $ \bigl[ \begin{smallmatrix}0 & 0\\ 0 & -2X\end{smallmatrix}\bigr]$ commute, so we can write:

$$ e^{i\frac{\pi}{4} \bigl( \bigl[ \begin{smallmatrix}0 & 0\\ 0 & 2I\end{smallmatrix}\bigr] + \bigl[ \begin{smallmatrix}0 & 0\\ 0 & -2X\end{smallmatrix}\bigr] \bigr)} = e^{i\frac{\pi}{4} \bigl[ \begin{smallmatrix}0 & 0\\ 0 & 2I\end{smallmatrix}\bigr] } e^{i\frac{\pi}{4} \bigl[ \begin{smallmatrix}0 & 0\\ 0 & -2X\end{smallmatrix}\bigr] }$$

this becomes:

$$ \begin{pmatrix} I & 0 \\ 0 & iI\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} I & 0 \\ 0 & e^{-i\frac{\pi}{2}X}\end{pmatrix} $$

using the property $e^{iaX} = \cos(a)I + i X \sin(a) $ with $a=\frac{\pi}{2}$ (you can look it up in the section 'Exponential of a Pauli vector'  in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices ) you get $e^{-i\frac{\pi}{2}X} = - i X $. So finally:

$$ \begin{pmatrix} I & 0 \\ 0 & iI\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} I & 0 \\ 0 & -iX\end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix} I & 0 \\ 0 & X \end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: You carried out the calculation but that is not what is being asked here.

Answer (score 3):

We can derive this equality by direct matrix exponentiation. First, note that $I-X$ satisfies the following:
\begin{align}
(I-X)^2 &= (I-X)(I-X) = 2(I-X)\\
(I-X)^3 &= (I-X) (I-X)^2 = (I-X)(2 (I-X)) = 2(I-X)^2 = 4(I-X)
\\&\vdots
\\(I-X)^k &= 2^{k-1} (I-X) \tag{1}
\end{align}

for $k\geq 1$, and $(I-X)^0 = I$ by definition. Then, using the definition of matrix exponentiation we can exponentiate $I-X$ as follows:

\begin{align}
\exp(i \theta (I-X)) &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(i \theta)^k (I-X)^k}{k!} \tag{2}
\\&= I + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(i \theta)^k (I-X)^k}{k!} \tag{3}
\\&= I + (I-X)\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(i \theta)^k 2^{k-1}}{k!} \tag{4}
\\&= I + (I-X)\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(i 2\theta)^k }{k!} - 1\right) \tag{5}
\\&= I + (I-X)\frac{1}{2}(e^{i2\theta} - 1) \tag{6}
\\&= I + (I-X)ie^{i\theta}\sin\theta \tag{7}
\end{align}

Line (4) uses Eq. (1), line (6) uses the definition of (scalar) exponentiation, and line (7) uses
$$
(e^{i\theta} - e^{-i\theta}) = 2i\sin\theta \tag{8}
$$

We can rewrite $I-Z$ as:
\begin{align}
I - Z  = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \tag{9}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

and so we need to solve
\begin{align}
\exp\left[i \frac{\pi}{4} (I-Z) \otimes (I-X)\right] &= \exp\left[i \frac{\pi}{2} |1\rangle \langle 1| \otimes (I-X)\right] \tag{10}
\\&= \exp\left[
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 
\\ 0 & i\frac{\pi}{2} (I-X)
\end{pmatrix}\right] \tag{11}
\\&= \begin{pmatrix} I & 0 
\\ 0 & \exp\left[i\frac{\pi}{2} (I-X)\right]
\end{pmatrix}\tag{12}
\end{align}
which is a block-diagonal matrix ("$0$" means a $2 \times 2$ matrix of zeros here). The last equality maybe isn't obvious, but basically since the matrix exponential is just matrix multiplication -- e.g. Eq. (2) -- and the matrix product of block-diagonal matrices is just a block diagonal of matrix products, we can exponentiate each block separately. Then, applying Eq. (7) for $\theta = \pi/2$ we get
$$
\exp\left[i\frac{\pi}{2} (I-X)\right] = I + (I - X)(i^2) = X
$$
And so plugging into Eq (12) we find
\begin{equation}
\exp\left[i \frac{\pi}{4} (I-Z) \otimes (I-X)\right] = \begin{pmatrix} I & 0 \\ 0 & X\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Comment: You carried out the calculation but that is not what is being asked here.

Comment: Check the edits. "Why can the CNOT be represented as $e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}\left(I-Z\right)\otimes\left(I-X\right)}$" was the original question title.

Comment: well, the title at the time I answered

Comment: Sorry for this. I saw my original title was edited by somebody slightly misleading so I corrected it - sadly to late. Nevertheless forky your comment is still very helpful for me! Thank you.