# Which book(s) us(es) the CNOT representation $e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}\left(I-Z\right)\otimes\left(I-X\right)}$?

Tags: quantum-gate, resource-request

I am looking for a book that uses the following representation of a CNOT , that so far I have only seen on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controlled_NOT_gate). Because I'd like to properly cite the source, I am looking for a book that uses it:

> $e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}\left(I-Z\right)\otimes\left(I-X\right)}$

Comment: related by the OP: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/26455/55

Comment: as a general comment: I don't think using such an identity necessarily requires citing a particular source. You can just include the derivation if you really want to be thorough, it's a pretty straightforward calculation anyway

Comment: Alright Thank you for your advice!

Comment: Im going to close the question then.